# Angular - How to set up a parallel for loop in event binding function?

Tags: html, .net, angular, typescript, event-handling

I have a function that expands every RowCol object in a FlexGridDetailProvider upon click. Right now, performance is bad with the way data binding works on FlexGrid rows, so I'm looking to improve performance by parallelizing each statement in the for loop.

Here's the typescript function:

```
    if (thisDetailProvider!= null) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        try {
          for (var t = 0; t < grid.rows.length; t++) {
            if (thisDetailProvider.isDetailAvailable(t)) {
              thisDetailProvider.showDetail(t);
              this.gridSelectionService.clearSelectionFromGrids(thisDetailProvider.grid);
            }
          }
        } catch (err) { console.log(err); }
      }, 100);
    }
```

I'd like the solution to be as simple as using the Parallel.For loop provided with C#. The solutions I've found so far require turning the event binding function into an asynchronous function, but I'd like to avoid introducing that complexity if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async function to achieve the reduced code complexity. It is same as promise.

```
    // `async` function | define a function start with `async` keyword
    async myAsyncFunc() {
        // #1   `async` ensures that the function returns a promise,
        //      even without explicitly return
        return 123;

        // #2   we can also `explicitly` return a promise 
        //      this works same as above return
        // return Promise.resolve(123);

        // we can do both the ways but
        // as `async` ensures that the function returns a promise
        // so why to write extra code to return explicitly
    }

    // calling a function - and to get return result call then()
    // the function inside then() will return the value 
    myAsyncFunc().then((returnVal) => {
        console.log(returnVal); // 123
    });



   async yourFunction(){
          for (var t = 0; t < grid.rows.length; t++) {
            if (thisDetailProvider.isDetailAvailable(t)) {
              thisDetailProvider.showDetail(t);
              this.gridSelectionService.clearSelectionFromGrids(thisDetailProvider.grid);
            }
          }
   }
```

In your case, I guess you can ignore the returning part which involves then